# Parsing Text Document Lines in Python on Wildcards/Patterns

Tags: python, string

### What I Have

I'm working on parsing a .txt file that contains scheduling information for who works when on a given day.  The .txt file looks like this:

```
START PAGE 0

XYZ Schedule for:  Saturday, March 30, 2013

Barnes, Michael8:00a10:00aTech

Collins, Jessica8:00a4:00pSupervisor

Hamilton, Patricia8:00a10:00aTech

Smith, Jan8:00a10:00aTech

Park, Kimberly8:00a10:00aTech

Edwards, Terrell10:00a12:00pTech

Green, Harrold12:00p2:00pTech

Tait, Jessica12:00p2:00pTech

Tait, Jessica2:00p4:00pTech

Hernandez, William (Monte)4:00p6:30pSupervisor

Tait, Chioma4:00p6:00pTech

Hernandez, William (Monte)6:30p7:00pSupervisor

Hernandez, William (Monte)7:00p9:00pSupervisor

Tailor, Thomas (Jason)9:00p12:00aSupervisor

Jones, Deslynne10:00p12:00aTech

3/28/2013 2:21:17 PM

END PAGE 0
```

So the first two and last two lines are not relevant but every other line in the middle is the schedule for one person.

### What I Want

I want to parse out the pieces of each line so that I can write it to a .csv file.  I can use `line.partition(',')[0]` to get the last name (the first piece on each line) but after that I'm at a loss.  I need to communicate the following to Python:

1. The part after the `,` to a number is a section (first
   name)
2. The part from the first number to either an `a` or a `p`
       (for am or pm) is another section (start time)
3. The part from the
           number just after that `a` or `p` to the next `a` or `p` is another
           section (end time)
4. Finally, the remaining section is another
               section (the type/position of the shift.)

A line in my resulting csv file might look like this:
`Barnes,Michael,8:00a,10:00a,Tech`

### Things to Note

1) One person can have more than one shift during a day.
2) Some people have a nickname in parentheses but some don't.
3) If Python had wild cards like `#` for a number and `*` for anything I could see how I might be able to keep using `partition` and keep splitting the remaining pieces, something like this:

```
for line in input:
    name = str(line.partition(',')[0]+','+str(line.partition(',')[2].split(#)[0]))
    output.write("".join(x for x in name))
    output.write("\r\n")
```

However, Python doesn't seem to use wildcards like that.  Also, this seems like a very inelegant solution.

Comment: You should take a look at regular expressions from the `re` module.  You can make a wildcard for a number as `\d`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be enough to get you started:

```
import re
data = '''Barnes, Michael8:00a10:00aTech
Collins, Jessica8:00a4:00pSupervisor
Hamilton, Patricia8:00a10:00aTech
Smith, Jan8:00a10:00aTech
Park, Kimberly8:00a10:00aTech
Edwards, Terrell10:00a12:00pTech
Green, Harrold12:00p2:00pTech
Tait, Jessica12:00p2:00pTech
Tait, Jessica2:00p4:00pTech
Hernandez, William (Monte)4:00p6:30pSupervisor
Tait, Chioma4:00p6:00pTech
Hernandez, William (Monte)6:30p7:00pSupervisor
Hernandez, William (Monte)7:00p9:00pSupervisor
Tailor, Thomas (Jason)9:00p12:00aSupervisor
Jones, Deslynne10:00p12:00aTech'''

print re.findall(r'(.*?)(\d{1,2}:\d\d[ap])(\d{1,2}:\d\d[ap])(.*)', data)
```

prints

```
[('Barnes, Michael', '8:00a', '10:00a', 'Tech'),
 ('Collins, Jessica', '8:00a', '4:00p', 'Supervisor'),
 ('Hamilton, Patricia', '8:00a', '10:00a', 'Tech'),
 ('Smith, Jan', '8:00a', '10:00a', 'Tech'),
 ('Park, Kimberly', '8:00a', '10:00a', 'Tech'),
 ('Edwards, Terrell', '10:00a', '12:00p', 'Tech'),
 ('Green, Harrold', '12:00p', '2:00p', 'Tech'),
 ('Tait, Jessica', '12:00p', '2:00p', 'Tech'),
 ('Tait, Jessica', '2:00p', '4:00p', 'Tech'),
 ('Hernandez, William (Monte)', '4:00p', '6:30p', 'Supervisor'),
 ('Tait, Chioma', '4:00p', '6:00p', 'Tech'),
 ('Hernandez, William (Monte)', '6:30p', '7:00p', 'Supervisor'),
 ('Hernandez, William (Monte)', '7:00p', '9:00p', 'Supervisor'),
 ('Tailor, Thomas (Jason)', '9:00p', '12:00a', 'Supervisor'),
 ('Jones, Deslynne', '10:00p', '12:00a', 'Tech')]
```

Read the documentation of the `re` module to understand the regular expression.  You can parse the names as a separate step or expand the regex to be more specific.  I recommend using the `csv` module to write to a csv file.

If you get stuck, post specific questions with code.

Comment: The first `.*` should be `.*?` to force a non-greedy match. Look at your result for "Jones" or "Green".

Comment: This makes for a much more elegant solution!  I've been reading over `re` but I must confess that all the stuff in that first variable of `re.findall` looks like magic gibberish.  Would you be so kind as to explain what the various bits of this are doing?  Perhaps show what the sections are (I'm guessing the `:` seperate the different pieces?)

Comment: The sections are called groups and are indicated by parenthesis.  `\d` indicates a number character.  `:` is a literal colon character.  Brackets (`{}`) indicate a number of repetitions.  Beyond that I'm too lazy to keep typing.  Read [Regular Expression Syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you you know how to remove the first two and last two lines, and that the rest is in a string called `s`, here is how I would do what you want:

```
entries = [x.strip() for x in s.split('\n') if x]

for entry in entries:
    ind = [i for i,x in enumerate(entry) if x.isdigit() and not entry[i-1].isdigit()]
    name = entry[0:ind[0]]
    name = name.split(',')

    other = entry[ind[0]:]
    ind = [-1]+[i for i,x in enumerate(other) if x in ('a', 'p') and other[i-1].isdigit()]
    shifts = []
    for i in xrange(1, len(ind)):
        shifts.append(other[ind[i-1]+1:ind[i]+1])
    position = other[ind[-1]+1:]
    print(name, shifts, position)
```

This will work on an arbitrary number of shifts.

Output:

```
['Barnes', ' Michael'] ['8:00a', '10:00a'] Tech
['Collins', ' Jessica'] ['8:00a', '4:00p'] Supervisor
['Hamilton', ' Patricia'] ['8:00a', '10:00a'] Tech
['Smith', ' Jan'] ['8:00a', '10:00a'] Tech
['Park', ' Kimberly'] ['8:00a', '10:00a'] Tech
['Edwards', ' Terrell'] ['10:00a', '12:00p'] Tech
['Green', ' Harrold'] ['12:00p', '2:00p'] Tech
['Tait', ' Jessica'] ['12:00p', '2:00p'] Tech
['Tait', ' Jessica'] ['2:00p', '4:00p'] Tech
['Hernandez', ' William (Monte)'] ['4:00p', '6:30p'] Supervisor
['Tait', ' Chioma'] ['4:00p', '6:00p'] Tech
['Hernandez', ' William (Monte)'] ['6:30p', '7:00p'] Supervisor
['Hernandez', ' William (Monte)'] ['7:00p', '9:00p'] Supervisor
['Tailor', ' Thomas (Jason)'] ['9:00p', '12:00a'] Supervisor
['Jones', ' Deslynne'] ['10:00p', '12:00a'] Tech
```